# Javascript constructor-mysql get trheadid

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, mysql-connector

i need to retrieve threaId from mysql.createConnection in my class. I use phpmyadmin and nodejs and in app.js i have var connected = new DBConnectionMySql(etc). It works fine but i can't access to first phpmyadmin hasndshake object. PROBLEM!! i'm sure i will got some other problem on my way if i continue to not have clear access to it. Or it will be okay to can't access this data?
When i talk about "data" i mean this :

```
<-- HandshakeInitializationPacket {
  protocolVersion: 10,
  serverVersion: '5.5.5-10.4.27-MariaDB',
  threadId: 492,   <--------------- THIS THREAD ID IS WHAT I'M SEARCHING!!
  scrambleBuff1: <Buffer 66 40 4b 3a 7c 28 4d 2a>,
  filler1: <Buffer 00>,
  serverCapabilities1: 63486,
  serverLanguage: 45,
  serverStatus: 2,
  serverCapabilities2: 33279,
  scrambleLength: 21,
  filler2: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00>,
  scrambleBuff2: <Buffer 2b 39 79 78 6d 3c 23 39 34 38 5c 48>,
  filler3: <Buffer 00>,
  pluginData: 'mysql_native_password',
  protocol41: true
}
```

Code:

```
module.exports = class DBConnectionMySql{
    host
    user
    password
    database 
    port
    mysqlobj

    constructor(host, user, password, database){
        this.host = host;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.database = database;
        this.mysqlobj = mysql.createConnection({
            user : this.user,
            host : this.host,
            password : this.password,
            database : this.database,
            debug : true
        },console.log(this.mysqlobj));
    }
    
    connection(){
        console.log(this.mysqlobj);
        this.mysqlobj.connect(this.connectionCallbackMysql); 
    }
    
    connectionCallbackMysql(err, ...args){
        if (err) throw new DBerror(err.code)
        console.log("This thread connection " + this.mysqlobj.threadId); <--- THIS IS UNDEFINED 
    }
    endconnect(){
        this.mysqlobj.end(function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("Closed connection");
        });
    }
    dbCallDatabase(){
        console.log('call query')
    }
]
```

Comment: Why do you need the thread id?

Comment: @Shadow actually for nothing, i want print in callback.